# How can I add multiple select options based on some html?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Basically I am looking to dynamically add (multiple) option tags to an select tag based on custom html content..

I am familiar with inserting dynamic content with ng-content, the rub here is the dynamic content needs to be separated out and wrapped in mat-option tags.

I need to be able to accept completely custom html in some fashion, it can be a div, or a list of elements or whatever, but it must be able to display custom html in the select options (not just simple strings as the options)..

Below is a very simple example but keep in mind I need to be able to accept any html.. (break it down / or whatever / and then display that html in my select)

-

Even worse, what I thought was going to work as a fall back, would be to use a single ng-content containing the multiple mat-options..

```
<hxgn-common-dropdown [dynamicContent]="true" [(value)]="selected">
  <hxgn-common-dropdown-items>
    <mat-option [value]="1">
      <span class="example">I'm dynamic content = 1</span>
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="2">
      <span class="example>I'm dynamic content = 2</span>
    </mat-option>
  </hxgn-common-dropdown-items>
</hxgn-common-dropdown>
```

And I was hoping that those 2 options would appear in my mat-select:

```
<mat-select>
    <ng-content select="hxgn-common-dropdown-items"></ng-content>
</mat-select>
```

Unfortunately, that just renders an mat-select with NO options..
I guess the mat-select doesn't work with ng-content?  Or am I missing something maybe?

Is there a better way to do this?

I am basically looking for any way to create a select based of off custom html.  That way devs can just supply some html to my control and it will automagically render the drop down list.

added stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-custom-options?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: have you tried ngFor ?

Comment: could you please explain more?  i'm familiar with ngFor but i dont understand how to break up the custom html content into separate option tags

Comment: It may not meet your specific needs.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pudrt4

Comment: Could you give more explanation of what you try to achieve? maybe the final output...

Comment: i want the end result to be a dropdown list with the first option of "I'm dynamic content = 1" and the second option of "I'm dynamic content = 2"  (if you look at my code example)

Comment: and i need it to work with ANY html content that is supplied (not just strings)

Comment: @dc-p8 thanks for the comment, same thing as far as the stackblitz link... how would you do that if you needed the options to be some custom html content.  it an be a div / list / whatever.  but i need to be able to accept html and create the select (not just strings, but completely custom html)

Comment: basically how would you ngFor through some html.  i see you're using a variable in the typescript that's a list of strings, how would you do that with html (not in a ts file)

Comment: that's easy to do but may i ask why don't you just use database ? like datasource to get your elements ?

Comment: i dont understand the question..  i need a dropdown control that devs can pass custom html to and it (as easy as possible) divides it up and creates the custom dropdown control options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could do it:
you could create a directive so that you can `Query` the directive. The directive doesn't have to have anything. 
Once you obtain the `List` of `Directives`, you can then **read** the `ElementRef` like `@ContentChildren(MyDirective, {read: ElementRef})`

Then you can render out the ElementRef however you like inside your custom component.
Setup a sample Stackblitz and I can work with you on that....

**Update:**
Instead of reading `ElementRef`, you wrap the content projected element in a `TemplateRef` and Query the `common-dropdown-items` from `common-dropdown`.
Then you loop through the `common-dropdown-items TemplateRef` as the content of `mat-option`.

refer to this stackblitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8dibtq

Comment: how's this for a start up:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-custom-options?file=index.html

Comment: i feel like its something like this: but can't quite but my head around it:  <div *ngFor="let item of someArrayFromDataInput">
  <template 
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{
      item: item
    }" 
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="tmpl"></template>
</div>

Comment: How's this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8dibtq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-dropdown.component.html
I need to redo your rig as bootstrapping the dropdown as entry component does not work.

Also, `mat-option` need to be inside the `mat-select` directly - otherwise it won't select

Comment: that's perfect!!  if you want to update your answer with some of that code I will accept it and give you the bounty!  thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using [JQuery Accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/)?

Comment: thx but i would like to stick with angular and the angular-material tool kits.  i just need some direction on the most designed way to break up dynamic content i do not need any other tool kits or libraries